# Question about why $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

We define a map $P:\mathbb{C}_\infty \to S^2$ by declaring $P(\infty) = (0,0,1)$, and $P(z) = \left(\frac{2x}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{2y}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}\right)$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ which is the stereographic projection.

Now, we define a metric on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$:
$$ d_\infty = \|P(z) - P(w)\| \ \ \ (z,w \in \mathbb{C}_\infty)$$

In my textbook it says that: "It follows that $(\mathbb{C}_\infty, d_\infty)$ is a compact metric space, since $S^2$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual metric."

I don't understand this. Is $P$ a isometry between $(\mathbb{C}_\infty, d_\infty)$ and $(S^2, \| \cdot \|)$? Or how I can prove it...

Comment: The definition of $d_\infty$ is given in a way that $P$ is isometry.

Comment: @Riemann, but here on Wikipedia it says that " It is neither isometric (distance preserving) nor equiareal (area preserving)": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Comment: Take Wikipedia articles with a grain of salt, the person who wrote this article did not read the same source you did.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So it is true that $P$ is an isometry? In my book is not given any hint. My intuition says that $P$ is an isometry...

Comment: For all $z, w\in\mathbb{C}_\infty$, $d_\infty(z,w) = \|P(z)-P(w)\|$, and by definition of isometry $P$ is an isometry. It does not require any non-trivial idea to prove, it just follows directly from the definition.

Comment: Your intuition is correct but in mathematics you prove things. If you understand the definition of isometry, the proof is immediate.

Comment: The statement on wikipedia is about the usual euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}$, not $d_\infty$

Comment: Just to check: You're asking about "topological" metrics in the sense of _metric spaces_ and not about _Riemannian metrics_, right? Have prior comments answered the question?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes. I'm asking about "topological" metrics in sense of metric spaces.

Comment: And now because $P$ is an isometry it is in particular a homeomorphism, and because $S^2$ is compact, we have that $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is compact. It's ok?

Comment: Be careful how you interpret the comments here. $P$ is an isometry because $d_\infty$ is defined to be the pullback of the metric on $S^2 \subset \Bbb R^3$. What does **not** follow from this is whether the topology induced on $\Bbb C \subset \Bbb C_\infty$ from this metric has any relationship at all to the standard topology on $\Bbb C$. Without further examination, this could be a completely different topology on $\Bbb C$ than you are used to. (It is in fact the same topology, but that still needs proving.)